# How can I plot a heatmap from my python dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multidimensional-array, chess

I have a python dictionary whose keys are **chess board positions** (64 positions) and whose values are the **number of captures** taken place at the board position.

```py
OrderedDict([('a1', 552),
             ('a2', 1128),
             ('a3', 1464),
             ('a4', 2328),
             ('a5', 2304),
             ('a6', 2088),
             ('a7', 1344),
             ('a8', 768),
             ('b1', 504),
             ('b2', 2544),
             ('b3', 3480),
             ('b4', 5016),
             ...
             ('h5', 2136),
             ('h6', 1968),
             ('h7', 816),
             ('h8', 336)])
```

To find the most "dangerous" positions of the chessboard, I wish to plot these values onto a **heatmap** using seaborn. To do this, the data should be converted to a pandas dataframe or numpy array where rows range from **1** to **8** and columns from **a** to **h** ([see chessboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOhtQ.png)). I need a data frame with the exact same layout of the chessboard shown.

**How do I transform this "linear" data into a 2-dimensional layout?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with help from @Quang Hoang:

```py
data = np.array(list(dic.values()) ).reshape(8,8) # transform to 2D
data = data.transpose() # transpose (swap rows with columns)
data = np.flipud(data)  # flip vertically to match chessboard layout
data
```

It returns:

```py
array([[  768,   600,  1896,  2592,  1440,  1008,   144,   336],
       [ 1344,  2304,  1512,  3192,  3096,  2712,  2280,   816],
       [ 2088,  2664,  5952,  5472,  4536,  7152,  3192,  1968],
       [ 2304,  4872,  7608, 16656, 11544,  6408,  4464,  2136],
       [ 2328,  5016,  7464, 15168,  9912,  5544,  3720,  2040],
       [ 1464,  3480,  6048,  4128,  4008,  5304,  3264,  1488],
       [ 1128,  2544,  1920,  2568,  2784,  1968,  2232,   720],
       [  552,   504,  1776,  1968,  1464,  1248,   288,   456]])
```

Which exactly matches the chessboard layout referenced in original post.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
# this would make `a`-`h` as rows
# transpose the data if you like
data = np.array(list(your_dict.values()) ).reshape(8,8)
plt.imshow(data, cmap='hot')
```

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn heat map is pretty straight forward.   Have generated full `OrderedDict` to demonstrated.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import random
import numpy as np;
import seaborn as sns

cb = OrderedDict([(f"{c}{r}",random.randint(300,5000)) for c in "abcdefgh" for r in range(8,0,-1)])

ax = sns.heatmap(np.array([bpv for bp, bpv in cb.items()]).reshape(8,8))
ylabel = ax.set_yticklabels(np.array([bp[-1] for bp, bpv in cb.items()]).reshape(8,8)[0])
xlabel = ax.set_xticklabels(np.array([bp[0] for bp, bpv in cb.items()]).reshape(8,8)[:,0])
```

[image]